# RegisterRawInputDevices making window unresponsive

Tags: c++, winapi

I wrote a function to register window to recieve raw mouse input using a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/inputdev/using-raw-input?redirectedfrom=MSDN#:%7E:text=the%20error.%0A%7D-,Example%202,-In%20this%20sample) from msdn.

```
bool N_RegisterMouseRawInput()
        {
            RAWINPUTDEVICE rid;

            rid.usUsagePage = 0x01;          // HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC
            rid.usUsage = 0x02;              // HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE
            rid.dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY;    // adds mouse and also ignores legacy mouse messages
            rid.hwndTarget = nullptr;

            if (RegisterRawInputDevices(&rid, 1, sizeof(rid)) == FALSE)
            {
                CYC_WIN32_LASTERROR_NOBREAK(false, "Raw Input RegisterRawInputDevices failed")
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

I call this once after calling `CreateWindowEx` and it is making the window unresponsive. The window still shows up, but you can't interact with it. It doesn't hang or crash either.

There are no error messages.

The application works fine if I remove call to this function.

Comment: Bug's in the code you're hiding. Show a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable I recently discovered that removing dwFlags i.e. setting `rid.dwFlags = 0` fixes the problem. Not sure whats happening there.

Comment: It doesn't *"fix"* the issue, it just stops your code from exhibiting it. The issue is still there. A [mcve] is required.

Comment: Hmm ok let me try and create one.